# Android: Se borra el contenido de los EditText

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy intentando hacer un sudoku. Al sacar el teclado de la pantalla o al acabar la edición se borra el contenido de los `EditText` que hay en el `Grid` mediante el `Adapter`.

El código es el siguiente y no se lo que esta mal.

```
public class SudokuAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    int sudoku1dimension[];
    LayoutInflater inflter;

    public SudokuAdapter(Context applicationContext, int[] sudoku1dimension) {
        this.context = applicationContext;
        this.sudoku1dimension = sudoku1dimension;
        inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return sudoku1dimension.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
       return sudoku1dimension[i];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View v, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View view = v;

        if (sudoku1dimension[i] == 0) {
            view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.emptycell, null);
            EditText edtxt = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.SudokuVariableNumber);
            final RelativeLayout rel = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.EmptyCell);

            edtxt.setId(i);

            edtxt.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                    if(hasFocus) {
                        final int position = v.getId();
                        // RelativeLayout rel = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.EmptyCell);
                        rel.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape_focused);
                        // EditText edtxt= (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.SudokuVariableNumber);
                        // edtxt.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    } else {
                        // RelativeLayout rel = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.EmptyCell);
                        rel.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.filledcell, null);
            final TextView txtview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.SudokuNumberFix);

            txtview.setText(Integer.toString(sudoku1dimension[i]));
            txtview.setId(i);

            txtview.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                    if(hasFocus) {
                        final int position = v.getId();
                        txtview.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    } else {
                        txtview.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        //we need to update adapter once we finish with editing

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por si a alguien le sirve lo he arreglado poniendo las siguientes dos lineas en el android manifest:

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Comment: esto provoca que no se abra el teclado virtual pero el  contenido, con esto mantiene en verdad el contenido?

Comment: Si, lo mantiene hasta que giras la pantalla.

Comment: @ogs1017 si haz solucionado el problema, podrías dar como solucionado. gracias

Comment: @josego Lo solucioné cómo comento.

Comment: @ogs1017 y donde esta la respuesta, hay un check, tenes que hacer click